# Как однозначно выполнять перевод int -> byte-> int в Java?

Tags: java, byte

```
int a = 412;    
byte c = (byte) a; //-100
int b = c & 0xFF; //156
```

Возможно ли в данном случае получить исходное 412?

Comment: 8 бит могут принимать только 256 различных значений.

Comment: ну я так понял, если больше 256 появляется число с - (-100 не знаю как)

Comment: Не всегда получается отрицательное. Только тогда, когда при обрезании старший бит будет = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

412 - это 32 бита 0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0001_1001_1100 в двоичном виде
Приведение к байту возьмет правый байт (8 бит), т.е. 1001_1100
Это есть -100 (десятичное)
Как переводить - инвертировать все биты и добавить 1 (в двоичном виде, конечно).
0110_0011 + 1 = 0110_0100 - это и будет модуль вашего отрицательного числа.
Откройте в виндовсе калькулятор (Программистский) и поэкспериментируйте там ))
Ну и приведение назад к 32 битам даст тот же набор бит, дополненный нулями слева: 0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_1001_1100 - это число 156.
И маска `FF` в данном случае лишняя. Вы все равно из байта не получите больше 8 бит.